# PHP's preg_replace() function is not replacing all lines

Tags: php, regex

PHP's preg_replace() function is not replacing all lines in:

```
12*some input
12*some input
1*some input
```

The code is:

```
preg_replace("/^(\d{1,2}[^0-9])/", "", $text);
```

The result is:

```
some input
12*some input
1*some input
```

But I want this:

```
some input
some input
some input
```

Comment: As it is a programming question this would be better suited to be posted on stackoverflow as coding is considered off-topic on superuser.

Comment: ya know but problem is who is dont know ask Question clear or spell mistake or no English knowledge  or  entry people all stackoverflow  1 or 2
Qus after cant ask!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how the implementation of PHP does it, I think you're missing either an option or your regex doesn't do what you think it does.

```
/^(\d{1,2}[^0-9])/
```

The above regex would look for 1-2 numbers followed not by numbers from the start of the string. Depending on how it works a line break doesn't indicate that `^` should match again.

If you look at the [PCRE Pattern Modifiers in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) you likely need to supply the `m` flag to turn on multi line mode.

In addition, though it's missing from that manual page, you might need the global flag. So the above regex would become:

```
/^(\d{1,2}[^0-9])/gm
```

You might also be able to test this regular expression on platforms like [RegEx 101](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: From OP [A. Sang](https://superuser.com/users/723622/a-sang): yes finally works: `/^(\d{1,2}[^0-9])/m`

Comment: I don't think (not 100% sure) the `/g` modifier is valid in PHP (in contrast to Perl).